How can I use Pundit to authorize for all controller actions? Or shouldn't I?
My site is for in house use only I added roles and role management because I'm gonna need some remote help from people who can read foreign languages shown in images and type them into the database I have a lot of CD's and DVD's and cassettes just titled "Unknown Chinese title" How can I use pundit to authorize on all controller actions instead of just specified actions because there are so many controllers with so many actions There's only one user with admin role, me, so I was thinking restrict everything to admin for starters and then I can work out the "editor" role priveleges later on Kind of like blacklist all from editor and then whitelist some to editor

Are you stuck with Pundit?  I've used cancancan to do this and it's one line of code.

I'm just getting started with it I didn't consider Pundit vs Cancancan

@BenTrewern I don't want to start a flame war but CanCanCan turns into an absolute shit show as soon as you need to do anything complex as you have to fight the DSL. The only real merit it has is that its deceptively simple to learn. I would never recommend it over Pundit.

I've used cancancan since it was cancan and found it brilliant.  Don't fight it, follow it's conventions and it makes your whole application cleaner and better.  Autoloading your controllers resources is maybe the best bit.  Each to their own.

Should be pretty simple to start with a before_action:
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Pundit::Authorization

  before_action do
    policy = Pundit.policy(current_user, controller_name.classify.constantize)
    next if policy&.public_send("#{action_name}?")

    authorize :application, :admin?
  end
end

# app/policies/application_policy.rb
class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :record

  def initialize(user, record)
    @user = user
    @record = record
  end

  def admin?
    user.admin?
  end
end

# app/policies/item_policy.rb
class ItemPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def index?
    user.editor?
  end
end

https://github.com/varvet/pundit#headless-policies

Thanks Can you tell me how I would then whitelist users with role :editor let's say, for a specific controller/action?

@fugeeohu revised. note that it is a bit backwards from how pundit is meant to be used. i suggest you add authorize method call  to every action, you app doesn't sound so big.
